# Convert String to Integer within Column in Dataframe (5 Star Rating = 5)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want to convert a column containing strings of reviews such as 5.0 out of 5 stars to an integer.

```
0    5.0 out of 5 stars
1    2.0 out of 5 stars
2    5.0 out of 5 stars
3    5.0 out of 5 stars
4    5.0 out of 5 stars
5    5.0 out of 5 stars
6    4.0 out of 5 stars
7    5.0 out of 5 stars
8    5.0 out of 5 stars
9    5.0 out of 5 stars
Name: StarRating, dtype: object
```

I am familiar with iterating over rows, and columns, and have tried

```
df[["StarRating"]] = df[["StarRating"]] .apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

but receive the following error

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "5.0 out of 5 stars" at position 0
```

I have also tried:

```
for col in df.StarRating()
    if df['StarRating'] = (df['StarRating'] !='5.0 out of 5 stars').astype(int, 5.0)
    if df['StarRating'] = (df['StarRating'] !='4.0 out of 4 stars').astype(int, 4.0)
    if df['StarRating'] = (df['StarRating'] !='3.0 out of 3 stars').astype(int, 3.0)
    if df['StarRating'] = (df['StarRating'] !='2.0 out of 2 stars').astype(int, 2.0)
    if df['StarRating'] = (df['StarRating'] !='1.0 out of 1 stars').astype(int, 1.0)
    print(StarInt)
```

but receive the error

```
File "<ipython-input-43-e2e6fd3fae34>", line 1
    for col in df.StarRating()
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Missing `:` after `for col in df.StarRating()`, to solve the SyntaxError. That still won't solve the full problem though, which is that you can't convert a full sentence to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the string and converting the first element to float:

```
df['StarRatingNumeric'] = df.StarRating.apply(lambda r: float(r.split()[0]))
```

or if you need integer data type:

```
df['StarRatingNumeric'] = df.StarRating.apply(lambda r: int(float(r.split()[0])))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are always the first elements in the strings you could also do this:

```
ratings = ['5.0 out of 5 star', '2.0 out of 5 stars', '4.0 out of 5 stars']
df = pd.DataFrame(ratings, columns = ['rating'])

df['stars'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rating'].apply(lambda x: x[:3])).astype(int)
```

It "looks" at every cell of the column 'rating' and takes the first first 3 elements from it.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I did df['StarsInt'] = pd.to_numeric(df['StarRating'].apply(lambda x: x[:3])).astype(int)